# имитировать клик submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, modx

подскажите, что-то туплю, как при клике на кнопки +- имитировать кнопку submit&

```
<form method="post" class="ms2_form form-inline" role="form">
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="{$product.key}"/>
    {if $product.options?}
            {$product.options | join : '; '}
        {/if}
    <div class="number">
        <div class="data-input">
            <input type="number" name="count" value="{$product.count}" size="5"/>
            <span class="plus">+</span>
            <span class="minus">-</span>
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="ms2_action" value="cart/change">
</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>


$('.number .minus').click(function () {
            var $input = $(this).parent().find('input[name="count"]');
            var count = parseInt($input.val()) - 1;
            count = count < 1 ? 0 : count;
            $input.val(count);
            $input.change();
            return false;
        });
        $('.number .plus').click(function () {
            var input = $(this).parent().find('input[name="count"]');
            input.val(parseInt(input.val()) + 1);
            input.change();
            alert(input.val);
            return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.number span').click(function () {
     $('.ms2_form button[type="submit"]').trigger('click');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelector('[name="ms2_action"]').click();
```

или

```
$('[name="ms2_action"]').click();
```

```js
function imitateSubmit() {
  document.querySelector('[name="ms2_action"]').click();
  // или
  $('[name="ms2_action"]').click();
}
```

```css
form {
  border: 2px solid lightgreen;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="console.log('submit');return false;">
  <button type="submit" name="ms2_action">Submit</button>
</form>
<br/>
<button type="button" onclick="imitateSubmit()">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как один из вариантов:

```
$('form button[type="submit"]').trigger('click');
```